Are Microsoft Media session events delivered on a thread?
Win32, Windows Media Foundation. I have a media session (IMFMediaSession) playing some topologies. I get an IMFMediaEventGenerator from it and request async events by calling BeginGetEvent().
Question, when the async callbacks come, do they come on a worker thread, or on message boundaries? The main (UI) thread of the app is apartment threaded, if that's relevant. I'd rather have it on threads.
If this is an implementation detail with no guarantee either way, I'd like to know that too.
Quick test seems to indicate - message boundaries. I could not mark the main thread as a multithreaded apartment, it would break things elsewhere.

"when the async callbacks come, do they come on a worker thread, or on message boundaries?" - that is really easy to test yourself. Simply call GetCurrentThreadId() inside your UI thread and inside your callback, and see if the IDs match or not.

That would be one test, on one OS, on a handful of media files. I'm more wondering whether it's contractual.

There's no contractual guarantee on anything related to threads (beyond COM rules), in fact sample here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-event-generators#implementing-imfmediaeventgenerator has critical sections and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/calling-asynchronous-methods clearly states that for example IMFAsyncCallback::Invoke implementation must be thread-safe

They are typically coming from thread pool managed by RTWQ API, so this will be typically a non-UI, background thread. But RTWQ queues can be window backed as well, although I doubt this is anywhere used though.

Also you could technically try supplying your own work queue via IMFAsyncCallback::GetParameters used with BeginGetEvent. The default implementation (what we may refer to as "guarantee" of some sort) is "standard" work queue which is not using windows and message loops for dispatching. That would give you backround MTA thread from a pool as the thread of delivery.

Since the UI thread in my case is a STA one, looks like marshaling happens anyway. Since the IMFAsyncCallback is introduced to MF on a STA thread, it seems like MF follows the COM rule - no direct calls from other apartments.
